# htmlentities() varchar and lontext fields different outputs

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a post comprising with `title` and `content`

After submit this information is stored in the bd using pdo

```
title = "qóqá áéíóú qqqqqqqq ÁÉÍÓÚ";  VARCHAR(20)
content = "qóqá áéíóú qqqqqqqq ÁÉÍÓÚ"; LONGTEXT
```

In the database, both has the same content characters

Once I output both contents, using `htmlentities()`:

```
htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding);
htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding);
```

in html, `title` appears correct:

```
qóqá áéíóú qqqqqqqq ÁÉÍÓÚ
```

but `content` appears like this

```
q&oacute;q&aacute; &aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute; 
qqqqqqq &Aacute;&Eacute;&Iacute;&Oacute;&Uacute;
```

regarding that both has the same characters content in the database

how do I fix this?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: The second text is encoded twice. You're surely not looking at the raw text but asking the browser to render it for you and looking and that output.

Comment: is not twice, let me check

Comment: yes it was, encoded twice. thank you, I would never realized it!! +1